# MVC user updated the entity ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

Assuming you have an ASP.NET MVC app and a `Post` method that allow the user update some entity

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, MyEntitie entitie)
{
    ...
}
```

How can you be sure that the user doesn't update the `ID` of the entity when sending the post request? If the user changes the `ID` it could make something fail in the DB or compromise the security of the APP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rule #1: Never trust user's input. Not even if it's your Grandmother**

Whether you have client side validation or not, you must validate the entered user data at the server side.

Simply make sure that the user have the permissions to update the entity with the id posted to the server before you handle the request and updates the database.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't.  Even if you make it hidden, user can still modify (including post request) it by opening page code or via tools like Fiddler.  You need to build security functionality on the server side.  For instance check if user has access and CRUD operations to that entity.